# Dropbox not working after Ubuntu upgrade 19.04

Tags: ubuntu, dropbox

After upgrading Ubuntu to 19.04 my dropbox stopped working. When I open the program, nothing happens, files are not syncing. Reinstalling didn't help. Any ideas?